# Input format to save page links by ID but render by the URL alias?

Tags: 7

I would like an input format that works roughly like this:

- I can enter links to other pages on my site using a special syntax, but importantly, I reference them by their current URL alias.
- When the page is saved to DB, the filter replaces them with node IDs, which never change.
- If I edit the page again, the filter replaces them back with current URL aliases before showing it to me. That way I know what the links are and I don’t even have to care that the DB actually stores node IDs.
- When the page is rendered, the links are rendered to the URL aliases, rather than node IDs.

Is there anything out there that does this already?

Why I want this: so that I can change URL aliases without breaking existing links. I do have automatic redirects created, but that's not quite the same thing. I want pages to link to the correct URL when I change an alias.

Comment: Yeah, I’ve always wanted that too. It’s so easy to implement and totally fixes the broken-links problem without that hack that is redirects...

Answer (score 0):

If you use an wysiwyg editor ie. CKeditor, there are contrib modules that offer you this functionality. For example, take a look at the [ckeditor link module](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link).
It let's you search for your nodes and make a link to the node path which is what is saved to your database. Drupal automatically shows the url alias frontend, so if you change your url alias at a later point, you will still have a working reference to your node.

Why is it important to you that you reference them by their current url alias?

Comment: When I want to link to a page, my browser shows its current alias. So it’s easiest if I can just use that, rather than find the node id. I’ll have a look at that module.